# media upload limits for posting on twitter via REST API

Tags: twitter

What is media upload limits to post pictures via REST API POST statuses/update_with_media?
Can it be different per user?

Comment: [read this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/uploads.html#uploadlimitdesc)

Comment: @WimOmbelets, thank you for response, but I am not sure how ArcGIS is relevant to Twitter API. After some research, I found that the limit for pic upload can be found only via X-MediaRateLimit-Limit of statuses/update_with_media. There is no exact number of pics upload without coding, which is too risky for the project. We opted out for posting pics on Flickr and use Twitter for text message upload.